# Is there a way to enable zipkin tracing in a jar such that wherever the jar is used, it initialises a separate span by-default

Tags: java, retrofit, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin, distributed-tracing

I am creating a client sdk with retrofit calls to a service, packaged as a separate jar. I have to include zipkin tracer/tracing in this jar so that any application using this jar to communicate with the service, have a separate span created automatically for every call to the service. Is there a feasible solution to my problem?

I have been trying to solve the problem using the "io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-okhttp3" library. I have also added the "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth" dependency so that the tracer-id is by-default generated. But adding this jar to a project which uses kafka-streams and the "io.zipkin.brave:brave-instrumentation-kafka-streams" dependency, doesn't automatically initialses a new span.

```
    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(UnwrappedCallAdapterFactory.create());

    // Enable zipking tracing
    HttpTracing httpTracing = HttpTracing.create(tracing).clientOf(client);
    httpClient.dispatcher(new Dispatcher(
        httpTracing.tracing().currentTraceContext()
            .executorService(new Dispatcher().executorService())

    )).addNetworkInterceptor(TracingInterceptor.create(httpTracing));
    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();
```

What I expect is that applications using this jar have by-default a separate span for every retrofit call they make through this jar.

Comment: You should be reusing the beans created by spring cloud sleuth (e.g. HttpTracing, Tracing) instead of creating them manually